# Selection sort on array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a simple(?) selection sort program in C that selects the largest integer of an integer array and places it in the location a[n-1], places the second largest number in a[n-2], etc until the smallest number is placed in a[0]. I've run through the below code on paper and it seems like it should work, but when I compile it I'm getting faulty results. Am I missing something obvious?

```
/* The program implements selection sort*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"

#define n 5

void GetArray(int a[]);
void SelectionSort(int a[]);
int FindMax(int a[], int high);
void swap(int a[], int p1, int p2);
void PrintArray(int a[]);

main()
{
      int a[n];
      GetArray(a);
      SelectionSort(a);
      PrintArray(a);
      getchar();
}

void GetArray(int a[])
{
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
       printf("Enter integer# %d", i+1);
       a[i]=GetInteger();
     }
}

void SelectionSort(int a[])
{
     int i, max;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
           max=FindMax(a,i);
           swap(a,max,(n-1-i));
     }     
}

int FindMax(int a[], int high)
{
    int i, index;
    index=high;
    for(i=high;i<n;i++)
    {
       if(a[i]>a[index])
          index=i;
    }
    return index;
}

void swap(int a[], int p1, int p2)
{
     int temp;
     temp=a[p2];
     a[p2]=a[p1];
     a[p1]=temp;
}

void PrintArray(int a[])
{
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       printf("a[%d]=%d\n", i, a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Don't try it on paper, run it through the debugger until you find the point where its behaviour diverges from what you expect.

Comment: I agree with Oli - also, you'll generally get a better response from questions here if you can narrow down where the problem is. A debugger or print statements will help you do this - and you may even find the problem without needing to ask :)

Comment: "I'm getting faulty results."   What input creates what result?  Give sample input, and show what you actually get.

Comment: This is why you should just bite the bullet and learn how to use `qsort` :-)

Comment: @TimothyJones Could you clarify what you mean by print statements? I haven't really debugged with that method and I'm not quite sure if I see how it could be applied here... (Sorry if this has an obvious answer, I'm a little new to programming).

Comment: @user1207214 Sure thing - commonly called "printf debugging", you can just put print statements inside your code and check the output by following it through. For example, if you suspect that your code is asking for the wrong swaps you could put `printf("Swapping positions %d and %d\n",p1,p2);` at the top of your swap function. If these swaps don't agree with the swaps you worked out on paper, you know there's something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these method to:

```
void SelectionSort(int a[])
{
     int i, max;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
           max=FindMax(a,n-i-1);
           swap(a,max,n-i-1);
     }     
}

int FindMax(int a[], int high)
{
    int i, index;
    index=high;
    for(i=0;i<high;i++)
    {
       if(a[i]>a[index])
          index=i;
    }
    return index;
}
```

I actually tested my answer and it works.

Comment: Off topic, but are you from the PhpBB support forum? I think I recognize you :-) But that seems to be working for me, I'll have to look at my previous code and see where I went wrong.

Comment: Nope - never even done any real PHP. But glad I could help : )

Answer (score 2):

Selection sort is process of comparing minimum element from the list and placing from the least index.
Now consider below code snippet.

```
public void selectionSort(int[] elements) {
    
    for(int i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        int minPosition = i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<elements.length;j++) {              
            if(elements[minPosition]>elements[j])
                minPosition = j;                
        }

        int temp = elements[i];
        elements[i] = elements[minPosition];
        elements[minPosition] = temp;       
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading, let me know feedback to improve from myside

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't:

```
       max=FindMax(a,i);
       swap(a,max,(n-1-i));
```

Be:

```
       max=FindMax(a,i);
       swap(a,max,i);
```

otherwise, next time through the loop, you'll find the same max value in the top position in the array.

Comment: But then wouldn't the highest number would be put in a[0], etc?

Comment: That's true. Your current version has the SelectionSort for decending sort, but the FindMax for ascending sort.  Daniel's answer fixes the FindMax for you.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic implementation of selection sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
       int i,j,n=7,a[]={1,2,5,3,8,9,5},key;
       for(j=1;j<n;j++)
       {
                       key=a[j];    //a[j] is the new element to be added to the sorted
                                    //sequence
                       i=j-1;       
                       while(i>=0 && key<a[i]) //traverse through the sorted sequence
                       {a[i+1]=a[i];i--;}      //until the place of key is found
                       a[i+1]=key;             
       }
       for (j=0;j<n;j++)
       printf("%d",a[j]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int removex(int arr[],int small,int n)
{
    int i=0;
    for(;i<n;i++)
        if(arr[i]==small)  //searching that no to delete
            break;
    for(;i<n-1;i++)
        arr[i]=arr[i+1]; //delete by overloading no
    return n-1;
}
void selectSort(int arr[],int sort[],int n)
{
    int j=0,k=0,small;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        small=arr[0];
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(arr[j]<small)
                small=arr[j]; //finding smallest no
        sort[k++]=small;
        n=removex(arr,small,n);  //removing that from list as we included that no into sorted list
    }
}
void main()
{
    int arr[10],arr2[10],i,n;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter how many elements");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    selectSort(arr,arr2,n);
    printf("sorted list is\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\n",arr2[i]);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Explanation please.

Comment: Why add another answer to a 4 year old question that already has an accepted answer? Especially if your new answer is just a dump of code with no explanation.

Comment: `<conio.h>` is not a standard header; `void main` should be `int main`; `clrscr` and `getch` aren't standard functions; you should never ignore `scanf`'s return value (actually, you should never use `scanf` for user input in the first place); that's also a potential buffer overflow.

Comment: @melpomene Thank You Sir for feedback